# Change of Variables in Integral, linear transformation

Tags: integration, linear-transformations

It's a really simple calculation, but i cannot figuere out my mistake.
I use the following change of variables

$ z_1=x-y \\ z_2=x+y \\ |\frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(z_1,z_2)}| =  \frac{1}{2}$

$\int_0^1 \mathrm{d}x \int_0^1 \mathrm{d}y (x-y)^2 = \frac{1}{6}$

$\int_{-1}^1 \mathrm{d}z_1 \int_0^2 \mathrm{d}z_2 z_1^2 *\frac{1}{2} = \frac{2}{3}$

The only mistake I can imagine, is the Jacobian, but I checked it very often :D. Do I mess up the boundary after the change of coordinates?

Thx very much in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limits are wrong after substitution. The axis-parallel rectangle (in $x$ and $y$) is not transformed to another axis-parallel rectangle (in $z_1$ and $z_2$). So, my suggestion is that you change limits. Try first yourself, and ask if you do not manage.

Comment: yes, your right, haha thx :D